# Arrange Data on MySQL

Tags: mysql

is there any way I can arrange this kind of Output?

[image]

I want the datetime and state seperated on the other column

The output should be like this:

company_id | name | datetime C/In | state C/In | datetime C/Out | state C/Out

Thank you

Comment: Google for "pivot query MySQL" ... this question gets asked many times per day here.

Comment: *The output should be like this* This needs `(company_id, state)` to be unique in table structure.

Comment: Only and always one in and one out per day guaranteed?

Comment: It should be first in last out @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nobody works over midnight you can aggregate by company,employee,date using a union to capture anyone who has signed out but not signed in. for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t 
(company int, employee int, dt datetime , state varchar(5));

insert into t values
(1,1,'2020-03-01 08:00:01','cin'),
(1,1,'2020-03-01 08:00:02','cin'),
(1,1,'2020-03-01 08:00:03','cout'),
(1,1,'2020-03-02 08:00:01','cin'),
(1,1,'2020-03-02 08:00:02','cout'),
(1,1,'2020-03-02 08:00:03','cout'),
(1,1,'2020-03-03 08:00:01','cin'),
(1,1,'2020-03-04 08:00:01','cout')
;

select company,employee,'cin', min(dt) cin,'cout',
         (select max(dt) 
         from t t1 
         where t1.company = t.company and 
                 t1.employee = t.employee and
                 date(t1.dt) = date(t.dt) and 
                 state = 'cout') cout
from t
where state = 'cin'
group by company,employee,date(dt)

union all

select company,employee,'cin', null cin,
         'cout', max(dt)
from t
where state = 'cout' and 
        (select min(dt) 
         from t t1 
         where t1.company = t.company and 
                 t1.employee = t.employee and
                 date(t1.dt) = date(t.dt) and 
                 state = 'cin') is null
group by company,employee,date(dt);

+---------+----------+-----+---------------------+------+---------------------+
| company | employee | cin | cin                 | cout | cout                |
+---------+----------+-----+---------------------+------+---------------------+
|       1 |        1 | cin | 2020-03-01 08:00:01 | cout | 2020-03-01 08:00:03 |
|       1 |        1 | cin | 2020-03-02 08:00:01 | cout | 2020-03-02 08:00:03 |
|       1 |        1 | cin | 2020-03-03 08:00:01 | cout | NULL                |
|       1 |        1 | cin | NULL                | cout | 2020-03-04 08:00:01 |
+---------+----------+-----+---------------------+------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```